# How to make the size of a QPixmap variable depending on the size of a QFrame/QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to program a QPixmap within a QLabel in a QFrame.
Putting the QPixmap in the label works fine so far.

But how can I set the size of the QPixmap variable so that it gets bigger/ smaller when I adjust the size of the window?

I couldn't find a phrase in the code which shows me the size of the QLabel or the QFrame...

This is my Code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(825, 668)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.set_pixmap()

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

    def set_pixmap(self):
        canvas = QtGui.QPixmap(800, 800)
        canvas.fill(QtCore.Qt.white)
        self.label.setPixmap(canvas)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: A pixmap has a fixed size and will look bad when scaled up. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: try with: `self.label.setScaledContents(True)`

Comment: If you want to keep the aspect ratio you're out of luck with QLabel, as it doesn't support it. There are only three alternatives: install an event filter and handly paint the resized pixmap, use a QWidget subclass that paints on its own, or use a QGraphicsView that only shows a QGraphicsPixmapItem and calls [fitInView()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#fitInView-1) for every `resizeEvent`. Note that in **ANY** case, you shall **NEVER** manually modify a file generated by pyuic (as the warning in those files clearly say) but you should use those files as imports only.

Comment: To understand how to correctly use files generated by pyuic, read the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).